# Jquery FadeIn Triggers Twice

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

Upon clicking 'text', a background image ('background') fades in. However - the background image fades in and out then fades in and stays on hover.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0tz131rr)

In other words - the code is being triggered twice. Here's the Jquery -

```
$(function() {
  $('#text').hover(function() { 
      $('#background').fadeIn(1000); 
  }, function() { 
      $('#background').fadeOut(1000); 
  });
});
```

Comment: show us with a fiddle?

Comment: its working here: http://jsfiddle.net/7s5w67sm/. maybe you're hovering over it more than once and its triggering it again? this is common. if its still doing the fade animation and you hover over it again, when the animation completes it will play again.

Comment: and here: http://jsfiddle.net/qgjfb1hm/

Comment: @AbdulAhmad fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0tz131rr/

Comment: @TroyMcClure, I am able to reproduce the behavior if I keep the mouse pointer on the "Hover here" for couple of seconds continuously... is that what you are facing too?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad  Seems that setting the position of the image was causing this. Without positioning it works fine. Only I want the image to be full width and height. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

If you rapidly jiggle the mouse over/off the `#text` div, it will trigger multiple fadeIn/fadeOut events. The viewport will show them all, continuing after you stop moving the mouse.

See the effect as you jiggle the mouse in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgjfb1hm/)

However, if you add `.finish()` before the fadeIn/fadeOut, only the final event will be visible.

```
$('#text').hover(function () {
    $('#background').finish().fadeIn(1000);
}, function () {
    $('#background').finish().fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Now try jiggling the mouse in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgjfb1hm/1/)

Comment: experiencing the issue even when I don't jiggle over the #text. .finish() is getting rid of the timing for the first fadein, then the next fadein is times at 1000. Still triggering twice

Comment: You're going to help us see it -- please make it happen in a jsFiddle.